# bind modifier combination to super

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like to bind some combination of keys on the right of the keyboard to super so I can access shortcuts like <kbd>super</kbd>+ <kbd>up</kbd> etc. using only one hand. Is this possible?

Using Ubuntu 18.10 with Gnome.

Comment: have you attempted using Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard -> scroll to bottom and hit + sign  to define this yourself

Comment: What have you tried?  Exactly what are you trying to do?  The question is just a hair vague as it stands.

Comment: I would like something like Ctrl + Alt Gr to be equivalent to super.